# Is it possible to change the libc for cpp program without source?

Tags: c++, linux, patch, glibc, libstdc++

I have built and installed another glibc from source, and I want to have existing executables written in c++ to run with the custom glibc for experimental purpose. In order to do this, i tried to change the loader of the executable. Firstly, a link named `ld_linux-x86-64.so.2` was created under /lib64 , with its path pointing to the new loader

```
sudo ln /home/ubuntu/glibc-2.27-amd64/lib/ld-2.27.so /lib64/ld_linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Secondly, the loader path in the executable was modified via text editor, changing '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2' into '/lib64/ld_linux-x86-64.so.2'. I launched the executable and got the following error:

```
./demo_cpp: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The patched cpp program failed to run and it seems that the c++ std lib is missing. However, this method did work for program written by pure C.  Using the method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710599/8706476), i tried the following command and get the exactly same error:

```sh
patchelf --set-interpreter /home/ubuntu/glibc-2.27-amd64/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --set-rpath /home/ubuntu/glibc-2.27-amd64/lib demo_cpp
```

So I wonder if it is possible to change glibc for a cpp program? Do i need to build cpp std lib from source too?

Comment: Loading an alternative shared library should not require installation of the entire system loader. That's something that's completely irrelevant.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Does that mean i can load modified glibc without changing the loader of the executable? How to do that?

Comment: This is explained in the `ld.so` manual page. it is unlikely that the executable will explicitly include the default library directories (`/lib` and `/usr/lib`) in it's `DT_RPATH`, if it has one. As such, the search path for shared libraries is overridable as explained in the manual page. The only exception to that is a suid program, which you did not mention.

Comment: Read documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), and compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g -H demo.cpp -o demo_cpp` then run `ldd ./demo_cpp`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm sorry the cpp code is causing misunderstanding. It is removed from question. Actually, my attempt is to patch glibc for existing cpp program without source

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Either improve it (by adding several paragraphs, with some [mre]) or send me an email (in English or in Russian) about it. Explain in several paragraphs how and why did you built and installed another glibc. See also https://linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: Are you allowed to use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) ? Are you allowed to use [schroot](https://linux.die.net/man/1/schroot) ? Please improve your question, and explain, in written English, what `schroot` and `strace` gave you. I am not sure you technically can patch glibc for existing cpp program without source, and in many countries that could be illegal

Comment: I guess you want to hijack some library functions. That's what LD_PRELOAD is good for. It's quite common topic on SO, especially hijacking malloc/calloc/realloc/free

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy thx. I will check the LD_PRELOAD trick, and see if and how it works for a cpp program

Answer (score 0):

### You need to read books about operating systems, compilers and linkers.

I recommend reading

- [*Operating systems, three easy pieces*](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/), a good textbook about OSes.
- the [*Dragon book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_(computer_science)), a good textbook about compilers.
- Levine's [*Linkers and loaders*](https://www.iecc.com/linker/) book.
- the documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)
- the documentation of [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)
- the documentation of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Once you have read all the above books, consider reading documentation of several Linux `man` pages, e.g:

- [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [gcc(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html), [ld(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html), [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [pmap(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html), [ps(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html)
- [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [waitpid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [chroot(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html)
- [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)
- [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)
- [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)
- [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)

#### Study also the documentation and the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and of the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/)

Since they are [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) !

> So I wonder if it is possible to change glibc for a cpp program?

Yes **it is *possible***, no **it is *not* easy!**

See also [schroot](https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot) and [LinuxFromScratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/)